# _.extend is undefined in js code generated from coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some `CoffeeScript` code, which is not written by me. I have compiled it to `Javascript` via a provided `Grunt` script and manually via `coffee --compile my_single_file.coffee`. In both cases, the following snippet is generated to loop over a list:

```
_ref1 = this.baseMap;
for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
  c = _ref1[_j];
  o = _.extend(c);
```

If I try to use the generated file in my page, the underscore in the last line is undefined. I guess I'm missing some includes, compile flags, ... but I found no hint what it might be. Any hint what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it depends on something else? Looks like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) although the `extend` method requires two arguments.

Comment: It was indeed underscore. Shame on me. ;-)